# javax.jdo.JDOFatalUserException (maven + datanucleus + jetty + com.mysql.jdbc.Driver)

Tags: java, maven, datanucleus

Environment: Eclipse, Maven

I have been following the [Datanucleus JDO Tutorial](http://www.datanucleus.org/products/accessplatform_3_2/jdo/guides/tutorial_rdbms.html) to no avail as I am stuck at Step 4. It has "information", but with no clear way to find it given I am new to Maven and new to Datanucleus.

All I wanted to do was switch a functioning project from AppEngine&[Objectify](http://code.google.com/p/objectify-appengine/) and port it to target a Linode (using a persistence layer like Hibernate or Datanucleus). This has been far from the "Straight Forward™" claimed on the tutorial.

I get the following error when the code is executing `JDOHelper.getPersistenceManagerFactory("datanucleus.properties")`:

```
javax.jdo.JDOFatalUserException: A property named javax.jdo.PersistenceManagerFactoryClass must be specified, or a jar file with a META-INF/services/javax.jdo.PersistenceManagerFactory entry must be in the classpath, or a property named javax.jdo.option.PersistenceUnitName must be specified.
at javax.jdo.JDOHelper.getPersistenceManagerFactory(JDOHelper.java:861)
at javax.jdo.JDOHelper.getPersistenceManagerFactory(JDOHelper.java:1099)
at javax.jdo.JDOHelper.getPersistenceManagerFactory(JDOHelper.java:919)
at myproject.HelloWorld.handle(HelloWorld.java:45)
at org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.HandlerWrapper.handle(HandlerWrapper.java:116)
at org.eclipse.jetty.server.Server.handle(Server.java:365)
at org.eclipse.jetty.server.AbstractHttpConnection.handleRequest(AbstractHttpConnection.java:485)
at org.eclipse.jetty.server.AbstractHttpConnection.headerComplete(AbstractHttpConnection.java:926)
at org.eclipse.jetty.server.AbstractHttpConnection$RequestHandler.headerComplete(AbstractHttpConnection.java:988)
at org.eclipse.jetty.http.HttpParser.parseNext(HttpParser.java:635)
at org.eclipse.jetty.http.HttpParser.parseAvailable(HttpParser.java:235)
at org.eclipse.jetty.server.AsyncHttpConnection.handle(AsyncHttpConnection.java:82)
at org.eclipse.jetty.io.nio.SelectChannelEndPoint.handle(SelectChannelEndPoint.java:628)
at org.eclipse.jetty.io.nio.SelectChannelEndPoint$1.run(SelectChannelEndPoint.java:52)
at org.eclipse.jetty.util.thread.QueuedThreadPool.runJob(QueuedThreadPool.java:608)
at org.eclipse.jetty.util.thread.QueuedThreadPool$3.run(QueuedThreadPool.java:543)
at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:722)
```

It would be nice to progress on from this as it just seems like it might require a few more days of reading up on all the required technologies to figure out what is going on, but I actually just want to get started, so if it is a day or two of "figuring out" I will need to just pick a "solution", which looks like it will be Hibernate at the moment.

I have made various modifications to the pom.xml, such as including ${basedir} as an extra classpath for the exec:java configuration, and copied in the [Datanucleus maven](http://www.datanucleus.org/products/accessplatform_3_2/jdo/maven.html) settings.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Seems to me that the error message is explicit

> A property named javax.jdo.PersistenceManagerFactoryClass must be
>   specified, or a jar file with a
>   META-INF/services/javax.jdo.PersistenceManagerFactory entry must be in
>   the classpath, or a property named
>   javax.jdo.option.PersistenceUnitName must be specified.

So "datanucleus.properties" isn't at the root of the CLASSPATH maybe? or you haven't got jdo-api.jar in the CLASSPATH, or datanucleus-api-jdo.jar maybe, or other jars. It would be a simple task to actually print out the CLASSPATH and present it in your "problem description", and with that the directory structure under that.

You don't say what you're entering on Step 4, because the provided README files tell you what to do and are verified to work; the provided Maven *pom.xml* works out of the box **with the provided samples**. As you say, you're "adapting it (TM)" to your own application, and you don't present what you've changed and why, where your code is etc.

Comment: Many thanks for the response. I have got this running now (without Jetty), it was due to the "datanucleus.properties" file not being on the classpath, so that's not too difficult to fix. My problem was just (a) not knowing for sure what is wrong because I did do some "class path stuff" and (b) that error message is not direct, it is three possible problems so I just found it difficult to really pin exactly what problem needed to be resolved first. ... should be sorted within a few hours as I need to sleep

Comment: Wait a minute, that error message says nothing about "datanucleus.properties" not loading! So that error message is *not* explicit because "datanucleus.properties" is a resource file that did not load, and there is absolutely nothing about that. It mentions that a "property named .... must be specified", but makes no mention that anything is a result of "datanucleus.properties" not mapping to any resource ... I even added in a "javax.jdo... property" mapping it to "JDOpersistenceManagerFactory" because of the description of the error message. It needs to be clearer on teh lack of resource file

Comment: When I run a simple case without the datanucleus.properties present in the CLASSPATH I get the above exception from JDOHelper (owned by Apache JDO project), BUT with a nested exception from DataNucleus that has message "javax.jdo.JDOUserException: You have either specified for this PMF to use a "persistence-unit" of "datanucleus.properties" (yet this doesnt exist!) or you called JDOHelper.getPersistenceManagerFactory with "datanucleus.properties" as the name of a properties file (and this doesnt exist in the CLASSPATH)". Maybe you have that too, or maybe you have some old version there.

Comment: Oh I see what the problem is, because it was running in terminal (at least that is what I would attribute the behaviour to) the debug output got truncated so the only error I was presented with was the one shown above with an additional indication of there being more. At least if someone else has the same problem this will show up in their search results. I've had my sleep now, going to have the breakfast I skipped and then get cracking asap.

Comment: I have conducted further tests to establish some other weirdness, http://www.datanucleus.org/products/accessplatform_3_2/jdo/maven.html includes `<scope>runtime</scope>`, which needed to be removed to run `mvn exec:java`. I had to take the extra time to *learn* every error, especially making note of which errors resulted from copying settings from articles. I still need to compile some notes, but my situation seems resolved for the time being. I will contribute back as much info as possible. I have accepted your answer and will supply my own for other people's perusal.